# Why do I see no logging from my custom Logger in the Visual Studio output window? (MSBuild)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, visual-c++, msbuild

I am building a C++ Project with Visual Studio 2019/2022, which uses MSBuild tasks.

Currently during a compile some of the messages that come back are not high enough importance by default to be displayed in the Visual Studio output window when logging is set to Minimal which I need to be displayed even if logging is set to Minimal.
I'm attempting to promote these messages to a higher importance so the logs that I care about still display in the IDE at build time.

I have created a custom Logger (written in C#, extending `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Logger`) that gets registered with the `BuildEngine` in a custom MSBuild Task.
The logger is very simple, just like is detailed in the "Build Loggers" Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-loggers?view=vs-2022

I have an MSBuild task (referenced from a props file) that is invoked at the beginning of the build, this task just registers the logger with the build engine then finishes.
The logger is then registered and runs for the duration of the build (I've tested this by confirming that subscribed events are firing by writing to a file and by creating another MSBuild Task which runs at the end of the build that just logs out all the currently registered loggers which confirms my logger is still present).

The strange behaviour that I'm seeing is that I'm unable to log out from the logger to the Visual Studio output.
I can get a log in the output by passing the `TaskLoggingHelper`, however this only works during the `Initialization()` invocation, any of the triggered events can use it but no logs get displayed. (I'm assuming this is because the helper gets invalidated once the task it's come from has completed).

I've also tried the basics:
`Console.WriteLine()`
`Debug.WriteLine()`
`Trace.WriteLine()`

But none of them work. It's worth noting that `Console.WriteLine()` **does** give me logs if I invoke MSBuild directly on the commandline, however I need the logs to be in Visual Studio.

And also Capturing the output stream using `Console.OpenStandardOutput()` and passing that through to the logger to use with `Console.SetOut()`.

I've also tried `Engine.LogMessageEvent()` directly with no luck (presumably for the same reason that the task it came from has finished).

Is there a way I can get my logger to write to the Visual Studio output when output verbosity is set to Minimal?
I've wondered if there is a way to get the current task (/the task that an event came from) in my logger, then grab that tasks logging helper, but I can't see a way to get the currently running task.
I've also wondered if there is some kind of global context I can get from my logger which would allow me to do this, but so far no luck.